# foreman dashboard is not opening

Tags: theforeman

I am trying to setup foreman and puppet master on the same RHEL7 server. I have performed following steps:

1. Install Puppet Server [Version: 3.8.2]
2. Install Foreman including smart proxy []

After installation I got the message similar to this:

Success!
  * Foreman is running at https://server.example.com
      Default credentials are 'admin:password'
  * Foreman Proxy is running at https://server.example.com:8443
  * Puppetmaster is running at port 8140
  The full log is at /var/log/foreman-installer/foreman-installer.log

But when I hit any of the below URL:
https://server.example.com    --- Foreman
https://server.example.com:8140   --- puppet master

I am not able to open the Foreman dashboard. I did not see any errors in Apache and other foreman logs as well.

Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: Do those domains actually resolve to the server you installed everything on?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you "obfuscated" the output, and it doesn't really say "server.example.com" ? If you have not, you need to probably start over with a proper DNS entry / hostname configured on your machine.

As a temporary test, run `ip addr list` then you can try going to https://10.0.0.123/ (or whatever the IP address is that is reported).

If you *did* obfuscate the output (change it to server.example.com from what it actually was), then what errors are you getting from the browser, or what are you seeing in the browser? This information would be helpful in troubleshooting.

~tommy

Answer (score 1):

First turn off firewalld.
If it's already off next check if SELinux is enforcing.

Either way, both should be on to be secure and look at Foreman docs for firewall configuration etc.